# Install webdeploy on W2016 IIS 10

Tags: msdeploy, iis-10, windows-server-2016, webdeploy-3.6

How to install web deploy on IIS 10 W2016?

So far I have tried

1. Using web platform v5 to installation of "**web deploy 3.6**"
2. After installation I have updated the web deploy service to run under local admin account.
3. I have manually turned off the firewall on the server
4. I have ensured that Management Service is running
5. Restarted server
6. I have verified using telnet that the port is open and then using **netstat -an** that the port is open and I can connect to it

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Comment: the symptom is that if you right-click on the site, you do not see Deploy in the Context-Menu. I guess Deploy will not work, either.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I have to install new management tool called "Management Service" in Windows Features

In order to install this:

1. Open server roles / feature
2. Find Management Tools
3. Check Management service

---

Update from other people experience

- you might need to restart the service
- Reinstall/Repair the installation of web deploy if you used installer

---

There is a option to install this feature using power-shell command(check the comment below) by Bart Verkoeijen.

This command is useful in case you are using **Desired State Configuration** (DSC)

Comment: Or PowerShell `Install-WindowsFeature Web-Mgmt-Service`.

Comment: also you need to "repair" or re-install the "web deploy 3.6" after this is done, or you will not see "Deploy" in the context-menu when you right-click the site

Comment: I installed the web management service feature, but it didn't seem to auto-start. I then did a repair of the web deploy 3.6, but it did not seem to work in this state. I started the service then uninstalled Web deploy and reinstalled it, and that is what seemed to finally work for me.

Comment: @JimGilmartin thnx for the info I am sure it will help others

Comment: @JimGilmartin Yep, same here. Repair didn't work, reinstall did. Thanks!

Comment: What is meant by "3. Check Management service" ? Where is this?

Comment: I see it can be reached from the IIS Manager, which is distinct from the Server Manager. To reach it, open Server Manager, click the IIS tab, right click the local server, click Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager, then select the local server. There, you can find Management Service.

Comment: Forgive the triple reply: I too found that reinstalling WebDeploy was necessary to get things working. I saw an Error 404 until I did so.

Comment: Re-installing web deploy 3.6 worked for us. Before that we were stuck on 404 on the .axd.

Answer (score 10):

I just did this on four servers,  had to install management service first, then web deploy (or reinstall webdeploy if already installed).   The management service install was in a slightly different location under server roles than described in other answers.

Hope this helps someone.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Answer (score 2):

Because the image from @Kevin Able's post seems to have disappeared, here is a new one.

[image: Add Roles and Features Wizard: Management Service location]

Comment: Note that the WebPI feed has been removed effective December 31, 2022: https://blogs.iis.net/iisteam/web-platform-installer-end-of-support-feed